# READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE doesn't work on Android 10

Tags: android, kotlin, android-external-storage

I'm trying to send a photo to the server, but I can't access the photo ONLY on Android 10. Made a READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE request, clicked "allow", in the settings, access to storage is allowed.

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Fragment**

```
private fun haveStoragePermission() =
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireActivity(), Manifest
       .permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

private fun requestPermission() {
  if (!haveStoragePermission()) {
     val permissions = arrayOf(
          Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
     )
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(requireActivity(), permissions, STORAGE_REQUEST_PERMISSION)
  }
}
```

The path to the file is displayed in logs. It's absolute, like `file:///emulated/0/...photo.jpg` , it is convenient, since you can immediately upload it to the server , but Picasso and server does not accept photos , or rather it does not seem to be allowed to read (Picasso displays placeholder due to an error). This code only works if you add `requestLegacyExternalStorage` to the manifest. Then everything works fine at once , but this attribute disappear in Android 11. I have no idea why exactly 10 Android doesn't work , although with test devices on 7, 8 , 6 everything is OK.

```
//Get images code
private fun getAllShownImagesPath(activity: Activity): ArrayList<String> {
    val listOfAllImages = ArrayList<String>()
    val uri: Uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val projection = arrayOf(
        MediaColumns.DATA,
        MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
    )
    val cursor = activity.contentResolver.query(
        uri, projection, null,
        null,"${MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN} DESC"
    )
    val columnIndexData = cursor!!.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA)
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        val absolutePathOfImage = cursor.getString(columnIndexData)
        listOfAllImages.add("file://$absolutePathOfImage")
    }
    return listOfAllImages
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> This code only works if you add requestLegacyExternalStorage to the manifest.

So, add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to the `<application>` element in the manifest.

> Then everything works fine at once , but this attribute disappear in Android 11

In Android 11+, to a large extent, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` works as it did in Android 9 and below. There will be some more areas that are off-limits, though.

What Google would prefer that you do is to stop thinking in terms of files and the filesystem, and instead use the Storage Access Framework (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`).

Comment: OK, I'll leave the Legacy attribute. I used to use `Intent.ACTION_PICK` to get a photo and change its path to absolute (from `content://...` to `file:///...`). Then Picasso could display a photo, but it was also not uploaded to the server. But thanks for the answer, I thought Android 11 would no longer work with requestLegacyExternalStorage.

Comment: @JaneySprings: "Then Picasso could display a photo" -- Picasso can display `content` `Uri` values. "but it was also not uploaded to the server" -- there are recipes for uploading content using a `Uri`, such as [this one for OkHttp and Retrofit](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html).

Answer (score 1):

By default, apps targeting Android 10 and higher are given scoped access into external storage, or scoped storage. Such apps can see the files within an external storage device without needing to request any storage-related user permissions
But you can add following property in activity xml to fallback to old behavior.

**android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"**

<activity android:name=".....
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">

But this will not be available for long time. You have to handle this according to new specifications for more details
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes

Comment: As I understand from the documentation, `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` should only be requested for devices with Android 9 and below, but what about Android 10? I just want to display all the photos from the gallery and select a few to upload to the server. I can add `requestLegacyExternalStorage` , but I want the app to work on Android 11 and higher.